# PowerShell "New-ADUSer" password complexity error

Tags: powershell

I will create 100 random AD users via script. But , I am getting the following error message for some random users.

```
New-ADUser : The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain.
```

Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy

output :

```
ComplexityEnabled           : True
DistinguishedName           : DC=contoso,DC=local
LockoutDuration             : 00:00:00
LockoutObservationWindow    : 69.10:39:00
LockoutThreshold            : 5
MaxPasswordAge              : 90.00:00:00
MinPasswordAge              : 3.00:00:00
MinPasswordLength           : 8
objectClass                 : {domainDNS}
objectGuid                  : 346664da-c908-470e-9fc3-5487983c92ae
PasswordHistoryCount        : 12
ReversibleEncryptionEnabled : False
```

Here is my script :

```
$UserList = Import-CSV -Path C:\temp\CreateUsers.csv
$targetOU = 'OU=Test,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$upnDomain = 'contoso.local'
$Path = "C:\temp\output.csv"

foreach ($Person in $UserList) {

    #If username does not exist
    if(-not(Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Person.Sam)'")) {
      
        $PassWord = -join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" |Get-Random -Count 10)
        $useritems = @{
            GivenName = $Person.Firstname
            Surname = $Person.LastName
            AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -force
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
            Enabled = $true
            DisplayName = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
            Name = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
            SamAccountName = $Person.Sam            
            UserPrincipalName = "$($Person.Sam)@$upnDomain" 
        }

        New-ADUser @useritems -Path $targetOU

        

        Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "Username: $($Person.Sam) Password: $Password"

    }

}
```

Comment: `-join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" |Get-Random -Count 10)` <-- this expression could generate the password `ABCDEFGHIJ`, rewrite it to take your complexity requirements into account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid creating passwords that do not comply to the domains password complexity rules, you could use this helper function:

```
function Test-DomainPassword {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Password,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$AccountSamAccountName = $null,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$AccountDisplayName = $null
    )
    # [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADEntity]
    $PasswordPolicy = Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    If ($Password.Length -lt $PasswordPolicy.MinPasswordLength) {
        Write-Verbose "Password '$Password' is too short. Minimal length is $($PasswordPolicy.MinPasswordLength)"
        return $false
    }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($AccountSamAccountName) -and $Password -match $AccountSamAccountName) {
        Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' includes the users SamAccountName"
        return $false
    }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($AccountDisplayName)) {
        # if ANY PART of the display name that is split by the characters below, the password should fail the complexity rules.
        $tokens = $AccountDisplayName.Split(",.-,_ #`t")
        foreach ($token in $tokens) {
            if (($token) -and ($Password -match "$token")) {
                Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' includes (part of) the users DisplayName"
                return $false
            }
        }
    }
    if ($PasswordPolicy.ComplexityEnabled) {
        # check for presence of 
        # - Uppercase: A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
        if ($Password -cnotmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") {
            Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' is missing Uppercase characters"
            return $false
        }
        # - Lowercase: a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
        if ($Password -cnotmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") {
            Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' is missing Lowercase characters"
            return $false
        }
        # - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
        if ($Password -notmatch "[\d]") {
            Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' is missing digits (0-9)"
            return $false
        }
        # - Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;”‘<>,.?/
        if ($Password -notmatch "[^\w]") {
            Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' is missing Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;`"'<>,.?/"
            return $false
        }
    }

    return $true
}
```

and use that in a loop:

```
do {
    $PassWord = -join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | Get-Random -Count 10)
} until (Test-DomainPassword -Password $PassWord)
```

If you add the `-Verbose` switch to the function call, you will see the reason why a password would fail.

Of course, this cannot test if a password meets the domains history requirement, that remains a trial and error thing..

---

Or you could re-use the code from `Test-DomainPassword` and create a helper function that returns a valid password like this:

```
function New-DomainPassword {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$Length = 10,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$SamAccountName = $null,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$DisplayName = $null
    )
    # [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADEntity]
    $passwordPolicy = Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $passwordLength = [math]::Max($Length, $passwordPolicy.MinPasswordLength)

    $count = 1
    while ($true) {
        Write-Verbose ("Generating valid password attempt: {0}" -f $count++)
        $password = -join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | Get-Random -Count $passwordLength)
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SamAccountName) -and $password -match $SamAccountName) {
            continue  # bad password, skip and try another one
        }
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($DisplayName)) {
            # if ANY PART of the display name that is split by the characters below, the password should fail the complexity rules.
            $tokens = $DisplayName.Split(",.-,_ #`t")
            $bad = foreach ($token in $tokens) {
                if (($token) -and ($password -match $token)) { $true; break }
            }
            if ($bad) { continue }  # bad password, skip and try another one
        }
        if ($passwordPolicy.ComplexityEnabled) {
            # check for presence of 
            # - Uppercase: A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
            if ($password -cnotmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") {
                continue  # bad password, skip and try another one
            }
            # - Lowercase: a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
            if ($password -cnotmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") {
                continue  # bad password, skip and try another one
            }
            # - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
            if ($password -notmatch "[\d]") {
                continue  # bad password, skip and try another one
            }
            # - Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;”‘<>,.?/
            if ($password -notmatch "[^\w]") {
                continue  # bad password, skip and try another one
            }
        }
        # apparently all tests succeeded, so break out of the while loop
        break
    }
    # return the new password
    $password
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$UserList  = Import-CSV -Path C:\temp\CreateUsers.csv
$targetOU  = 'OU=Test,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$upnDomain = 'contoso.local'
$Path      = "C:\temp\output.csv"

foreach ($Person in $UserList) {

    #If username does not exist
    if(-not(Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Person.Sam)'")) {
        $accountName = $Person.Sam
        $displayName = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
        $Password = New-DomainPassword -Length 10 -SamAccountName $accountName -DisplayName $displayName
        $useritems = @{
            GivenName             = $Person.Firstname
            Surname               = $Person.LastName
            AccountPassword       = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -force
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
            Enabled               = $true
            DisplayName           = $displayName
            Name                  = "$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
            SamAccountName        = $accountName
            UserPrincipalName     = "$($Person.Sam)@$upnDomain"
            Path                  = $targetOU
        }

        New-ADUser @useritems

        Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "Username: $accountName Password: $Password"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi theo , I have issue about DG Owner list . Have you had a chance take a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736533/get-distribution-list-muliple-owners-in-exchange

Answer (score 1):

Your random password generator is very poor and you do not guarantee that it meets your requirements. There is a .NET function, that you can use to generate random passwords: [`.GeneratePassword(Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword?view=netframework-4.8).

The first argument specifies the length of the password and the second argument specifies the minimum number of special characters.

You can use the following PowerShell function to generate a random password according to your needs:

```
function Get-RandomPassword {
    
    param($Length = 8) # Default length of 8, if not provided
    
    # Generate a random password with at least one special character
    $password = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($Length, 1)
    
    # Check password complexity
    if ($password -cnotmatch '[A-Z]' -or $password -cnotmatch '[a-z]' -or $password -cnotmatch '\d') {
        # Recursively generate a new password if the complexity requirements are not met
        return Get-RandomPassword -Length $Length
    } else {
        # Return the password, if the complexity requirements are met
        return $password
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
PS C:\> Get-RandomPassword -Length 10
A8$JfE1e%i
```

The function generates a random password of the provided length and with at least one special character. It then checks if all other (your individual) requirements are met. If not, the function will call itself recursively, until a password is found, that meets all complexity criteria.

To be honest, it's not the best design, as it might run forever in theory, but you will rather win a lottery than seeing this function running forever ;-)