# Powershell: Create CSV entries

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV File and in Column 1 are words.

I want to modify the words, for example I want to add the String "cat" at the end and write it down in Column 2.

I've posted a Question days ago where @Theo archived this:

```
$CSV = Import-CSV -Path 'C:\path.csv' -Header Column1

$newCsv = foreach ($row in $CSV) {
    # output an Object that gets collected in variable $newCsv
    # Select-Object * takes everything already in $row, 
    # @{Name = 'Column2'; Expression = {$row.Column1 + 'cat'}} adds the extra column to it.
    $row | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Column2'; Expression = {$row.Column1 + '-cat'}}
}

# output on screen:
$newCsv

# output to new CSV file
$newCsv | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\path.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output (on screen):

```
Column1 Column2
------- -------
Wild    Wildcat
Copy    Copycat
Hell    Hellcat
Tom     Tomcat 
Snow    Snowcat
```

As far as good, now I want to create and write down a Password in Column 3.
So I would create a variable with a randomized Password with some of the many PS generators already posted online.

And I also would like to declare Column1 and Column2 as a variable because I need those 3 Column entries further down the road to create a .txt File that include those.

Just if you curious why the hell do I create a .txt File AND a CSV:
Column1 is basicly a Systemname, Column2 Username and Column3 a Password.
I document access data in the CSV and create a Script in the .txt, so I can create the User in the Exchange by Script (for about 1000+ Systems).

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: It looks like your only question here is "How to generate randomized passwords with PowerShell?", because the rest of your requirements is already answered in your own code. Try to research for a moment, there is no way that generating random strings with PowerShell has not been covered anywere yet.

Comment: To generate valid password, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67387184/9898643). To write that password in the new `Column3`, simply create a new password in the loop first using that function `New-DomainPassword` like `$Password = New-DomainPassword` and add `, @{Name = 'Column3'; Expression = {$Password}}` on the `Select-Object` line

Comment: @Theo sorry for asking again, but I'm at a point where I can write down Column1, 2 and 3 with the generated password in the csv. But as mentioned befor, I also would like to create a .txt File that include those 3 entries. But are Column1, Column2 and so on variables? Because I try to display them with `Write-Output $Column2` or `$row.Column2` but it seem to not work?

Comment: @Ladi No, they are 'headers' or PropertyNames. If you have your `$newCsv`, you can iterate the rows and get a certain value using `foreach ($row in $newCsv) { $row.Column3 }`. If you want to write it out as _unstructured text_ you can do something like `$newCsv | ForEach-Object { Add-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\Textfile.txt' -Value ('{0} - {1} - {2}' -f $_.Column1, $_.Column2, $_.Column3) -PassThru }`