# Get Distribution List muliple Owners in exchange

Tags: powershell

i need a power shell cmd or script which will give me the list of all the Distributions list along with the OWNERS of that like managed by.

But , if there are multiple users inside managedby attribute  then I am getting `System.Object[]`.

My question are :

1- how can we get multiple users for managedby attribute ?

2- how can we add employeeid and samaccountname for managedby users ?

3 - if there is no managed by user then  it display "NO MANAGED BY USER"

4-  I want to get mail groups not hidden.

script :

```
$DGroups=Get-DistributionGroup -resultsize unlimited
$mastertable=@()
ForEach($Group in $DGroups){
    $table=[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                                Name = $group.name
                                "Managed By" = $group.managedby.name
                                "DistinguishedName" = $group.DistinguishedName
                                

                                    }
$Mastertable += $table

}


$Mastertable |  export-csv C:\tmp\managedby.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My output :

```
"Name","Managed By","DistinguishedName"
"IT research","System.Object[]","CN=IT research,OU=TEST,DC=contoso,DC=com"
"Test Mail Group 1","User01","CN=\Test Mail Group 1,OU=Test,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com"
"Test Mail Group 2",,"CN=\Test Mail Group 2,OU=Test,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com"
```

My desired output :

```
"Name","Managed By","DistinguishedName","OWNERSAMACCOUNTNAME","OWNEREMPLOYEEID"
"IT research","User01;User02","CN=IT research,OU=TEST,DC=contoso,DC=com","tst124;tst125","242333;344232"
"Test Mail Group 1","User01","CN=\Test Mail Group 1,OU=Test,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com","tst124","242333"
"Test Mail Group 2","NO MANAGED BY USER","CN=\Test Mail Group 2,OU=Test,OU=COMPANY,DC=contoso,DC=com"
```

---

LAST UPDATE :

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$group.ManagedBy


OrgHierarchyToIgnore : 
IsDeleted            : False
Rdn                  : CN=John T
Parent               : contoso.com/COMPANY/IT
Depth                : 5
DistinguishedName    : CN=John T,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com
IsRelativeDn         : False
DomainId             : contoso.com
PartitionGuid        : 59ce2f71-eaa2-4ddf-a4fa-f25069d0b324
PartitionFQDN        : contoso.com
ObjectGuid           : 62d578e8-b69c-45bc-967a-e530d72792e1
Name                 : John T
```

---

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$group.ManagedBy | ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeId }
Get-ADUser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties 
do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:42
+ $group.ManagedBy | ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeId }
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (contoso.com/COMPANY/IT/John T:PSObject) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: Can you run a *Get-Member* of *$DGroups* and share the type of object *managedby* is? Also, have you tried *$group.managedby.name.tostring()*?

Comment: hi , I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding the `ManagedBy` attribute stores the DistinguishedName(s) of one or more users (or none at all).

I haven't tested this myself, but you could try:

```
$DGroups     = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited
$mastertable = foreach($group in $DGroups) {
    # initialize a PsCustomObject
    $data = [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name                = $group.Name
        DistinguishedName   = $group.DistinguishedName
        ManagedBy           = 'NOT MANAGED'
        OwnerSamAccountName = $null
        OwnerEmployeeId     = $null
    }

    if ($group.ManagedBy) {
        $managedBy                = $group.ManagedBy | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Properties EmployeeId }
        $data.ManagedBy           = $managedBy.Name -join ';'
        $data.OwnerSamAccountName = $managedBy.SamAccountName -join ';'
        $data.OwnerEmployeeId     = $managedBy.EmployeeId -join ';'
    }
    # output this data to be collected in $mastertable
    $data
}


$mastertable |  Export-Csv 'C:\tmp\managedby.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks Theo But I have getting an error.  I have updated my question (LAST UPDATE)

Comment: It's telling you the exact error. Check the psitem passed to see what it is, that it contains

Comment: @Arbelac Aha, so my understanding about what is in a `ManagedBy` property was wrong. Thanks for sharing it. I have now updated this on Get-ADUser.